# Concatenate a string with multiple values in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, concatenation

I have created a ListView which is populated with an XMLParser and the user is allowed to select multiple values from the List using checkboxes and then can go to the next activity by pressing a button.
 On the Activity 2 I want to retrieve all of those values which were selected.

To get all of the selected values I use: `String selected += "\n- " +c.getName();`
where c is `final ConfigOptions c = options.get(position);`

Also I declared it outside of onCreate method like this

```
public static String selected = null;
```

But I have same issues

The problem is that on Activity 2 I get all the selected values but one of the value is null

> EX: null \n -Servotronic \n -Park distance control \n - Speed limit
>   info

Also, if I try to reopen Activity 1 and select new items again, on the second activity the old activities which were selected before are there too. Even if I set the value of the string to null, I still get all of them there.

So how can I concatenate the values of this string to not get anymore the null value in the next activity and also to be able to reset the value so I can make the selection again ?

Comment: you need to write `null-check` condition.

Comment: Perhaps it's because you are declaring a string and adding to it '+=' on the same line?

Comment: String selected += "\n" is a syntax error.

Comment: I tried declaring it outside of onCreate method and tried your method but there are same issues.

Comment: @StuPointerException after that "\n" is a + . I use it so I have the options on new lines, not one after another. In the EX: I posted \n so people know every item is on a new line.

Comment: @Catalin H I get a compile error with     String something += ""; which is the same as String something = something + "";  The variable 'something' isn't initialised at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Android `Bundle`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) to accomplish the task and in a better way. Create a ArrayList of the items to pass, add the ArrayList to the `Bundle` and send the `Bundle` in the `Intent` call.

Answer (score 1):

When the user wants to go to Activity 2, make a String array to hold the number of selected items. Add it as an extra in your intent to start Activity 2.

```
int count = // get number of selections
String[] options = new String[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    options[i] = // ith selection
}
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
intent.putExtra("options", options);
startActivity(intent);
```

In Activity 2's onCreate:

```
String[] options = getIntent.getStringArrayExtra("options");
if (options != null) {
    // process the strings here.
}
```